# Avoid long running transaction with huge amount of modifications

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to find a article about long running transactions on PostgreSQL (or other) DBMS systems.

From my perspective and experience from my over 10 years of Sybase ASE optimization on systems with huge amount of concurrent users is to absolutely avoid transactions that last longer than a couple of seconds without ignoring the safety of the data.

With PostgreSQL I guess it is a good way of working to avoid this too. 
It would be nice to find a article with a proof that this is right to convince my colegues. 
Of course I can show them how insert statements and updates and selects are locking each other. 
But maybe somebody has done this before.

Thanks.

Comment: In Sybase you would avoid them because of the stupid locking mechanism it has where readers are blocked by writers. This won't happen in Postgres. However you should still avoid long running transactions to help auto-vacuum clean up. By "long running" I would think of "hours". Having transactions that last several seconds or even minutes are no problem (assuming you properly terminate them)

Comment: SELECT statements should not block INSERT, UPDATE and DELETES. Are you using SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level or SELECT with FOR UPDATE clause ?

Comment: No, we use READ_COMMITTED (default). But read committed also exists on Sybase ASE. And in PostgreSQL the writers don't block readers? There is also similar types of read and write locks. Can you give more details.